# iOS 8 apps submission and new versions of apps from today on

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios8, appstore-approval

As you know, Apple has just made available the Xcode 6 GM seed and announced that we can now submit iOS 8 apps ([Submit Your iOS 8 Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09082014b)). However, I have a question: does it mean that, starting today, is it required to submit app updates with the new Xcode 6? Can I still use Xcode 5.1.1 (Base SDK iOS 7.1)? If not, could I keep submitting apps with Base SDK targeting iOS 7.1 with Xcode 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm in the midst of submitting an update right now and iTunesConnect states that builds can be submitted with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or Application Loader 2.9.1 or later.

Comment: You must submit your app with the latest version of Xcode according to Apple support

Comment: Just submitted with 5.1.1. Guess we'll see if it gets rejected.

Comment: Yes, you should use the latest version of Xcode available on the Mac App Store to submit your apps. As Starscream said, the latest version is 5.1.1 on the Mac Appstore

Comment: Thanks u all for replying

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, you can still use Xcode 5.1.1 to update your apps.
Xcode 5.1.1 is the latest version on the App Store !

> You should use the latest version of Xcode available on the Mac App
>   Store to submit your apps. ([Xcode Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/))

Hope this can help you ;)

Comment: last version on the app store is 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing (September 12th 2014) you can submit apps with both Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6 GM seed. So both SDKs are allowed. As soon as iOS 8 comes out, the App Store version of Xcode will show an update to Xcode 6.0.

Going by past experiences, at that point you will still be able to download Xcode 5.1.1 from the developer portal and still be able to submit apps with it for a few more weeks/months until Apple will officially announce that the new iOS 8 SDK is required for app submission.

Watch that newsfeed at https://developer.apple.com/news/